# How is concurrency handled in django?

Tags: python, django

I'm coming from java & spring framework. In spring, there's a clear mention of how many instances of your classes are running, and whether two threads can be given the same instance of a class, so you know if you need to take care of thread-safety in some operations.

I'm reading django's documentation and I'm seeing no mention of what happens under the hood. For example, how are class based views instantiated? Do all threads share a common instance of the class? Is a single instance created for each request? Similar questions for model classes. Is there any mention of such topics in the documentation?

Comment: Django doesn't deal with - or care about - concurrency at all. That is entirely the responsibility of the server.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: still, what the framework does matters. If, eg, in creates a single instance of a view class for all threads, that means thread safety is an issue

Comment: Django's own code is thread safe of course, if that's what you're asking

Comment: Django doesn't deal with - or care about - concurrency at all. That is entirely the responsibility of the server.